# How can i use text field and button search to find api id

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-test

This is my code now now i can call api form my sever and i want to know , How can i create text field and button for click to search api id on my emulator

- Now i try to create about text field first but i don't know where can i put text field in my code i try to put in body and in child also , it's dosen't work also

```
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
      final response =
      await http.get(Uri.parse('http://192.168.176.131:3000/api/courses/1'));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
        // then parse the JSON.
        return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      } else {
        // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
        // then throw an exception.
        throw Exception('Failed to load album');
      }
    }
    class Album {
      final int userId;
      final int id;
      final String title;
      Album({
        required this.userId,
        required this.id,
        required this.title,
      });
      factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return Album(
          userId: json['userId'],
          id: json['id'],
          title: json['title'],
        );
      }
    }
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      late Future<Album> futureAlbum;
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Fetch Data Example',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Fetch Data Example'),
            ),
    
            body: Center(
              child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
                future: futureAlbum,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Text(snapshot.data!.title);
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                  }
    
                  // By default, show a loading spinner.
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lots of options depending on the layout you want for your view. [TextField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html) is the control you likely will want to use for entering the search keyword. [TextEditingController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) is recommended to use for getting the value and otherwise managing the TextField.

Add the `TextEditingController` to your widget:

```
TextEditingController searchController = new TextEditingController();
```

In the body of your Scaffold, you will want to be able to have a list of widgets that display. In this example, I stack the widgets by wrapping them in a [Column](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html). The TextField and the [FlatButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlatButton-class.html) are inside of a [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) using [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) to lay them out inline with each other. Text entry on left, button on right. The row is thrown in a `Container`. When you press the button, a message will be printed to the console containing the keyword(s) entered into the text field. This is your opportunity to search through your data and adjust what is displayed to the user based on the results of that search.

Here is the build method I have created:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),

        body: Column(children: [
          Container(
            child: Row(children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: TextField(
                  controller: searchController
                )
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print("this is the text to search for => ${searchController.text}");
                  },
                  child: Text("Search"),
                )
              )
            ],)
          ),
          Center(
            child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
              future: futureAlbum,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text(snapshot.data?.title);
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                }
                // By default, show a loading spinner.
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],)
        
      ),
    );
```

Comment: You mean put in this one ? 
 
Widget build(BuildContext context) 
{
   TextEditingController searchController = new TextEditingController();

but now show 1 errors 1 warring 
1 .The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. ont thie "(snapshot.data?.title)"                             
1. warring .'FlatButton' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use TextButton instead. See the migration guide in flutter.dev/go/material-button-migration-guide). This feature was deprecated after v1.26.0-18.0.pre..

Comment: I'm using Flutter 1.22.6 due to package support and a delay in upgrading. Null Safety does not exist in my environment. That's why I changed ! to ? in this line: `return Text(snapshot.data?.title);` Also, FlatButton isn't needed. You can replace with any button that is not deprecated in your version of Flutter. What other info do you need to know? You're question is kind of vague. Although my answer is for an older version, the concepts still apply in newer versions of Flutter.

Comment: i also change type to this one so program can run , but is show   list dynamic is not a subtype of type map string dynamic on my emulator do you know ? How can i fix it ?

Comment: It's hard to say with the info available to me. A guess would be that your API call is maybe returning an Array instead of a single object which would throw this error at this line: `return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));` because it is expecting the parsed object to be a Map<String, dynamic> `{id: '', title: '', ...}` not a List<dynamic> `[{id: '', title: '', ...}]`

Comment: You think if i want to try to fix , how can i do it ?